# Limiting the depth of recursion Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

How can I limit this recursion function, so it will just stop recalling after maximum 23 times? However, I wouldn't like to modify the definition of the function binf.

```
binf :: Double -> [Int]
binf 0 = []
binf x =
  [fromIntegral(truncate x)] ++
  binf(x*2-fromIntegral(truncate x*2))
```

Comment: You add an extra parameter: the recursion depth. But the question is more: "what do you want to return in that case"?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you don't want to modify the type of binf (`Double -> [Int]`) but can modify the content of it? If yes, you can add an enclosed function that takes the depth as additional parameter and thus hide that away from the caller

Comment: Here however you can use `take 23 (binf some_x)`, since due to Haskell's laziness, you will then stop calling the `binf`.

Comment: Thank you, take 23 worked perfectly!

Comment: The second case can be simplified: `binf x = truncate x : binf (x*2 - fromIntegral (truncate x*2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In General**
You can wrap the recursion within an inner function. For example this function returns a list of descending numbers, starting with the input number `x`.

```
binf :: Int -> [Int]
binf x = go x 23
    where
        go :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
        go 0 _ = []
        go _ 0 = []
        go y rec = [y] ++ (go (y-1) (rec-1))
```

Here, `rec` is a recursion counter and the recursion ends when it reaches 0 or when the recursion ended naturally by the input being 0.
If you run `binf 50`, you will get a result `[50, 49, ... , 28]`, which has a length of 23 - the number specified as initial `rec`.

**In your case**
Since your recursion is just appending to a list, and haskell features lazy evaluation, you can solve this differently:

> Here however you can use `take 23 (binf some_x)`, since due to Haskell's
>   laziness, you will then stop calling the binf.
>   - [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) ([comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871593/limiting-the-depth-of-recursion-haskell#comment92656790_52871593))